# HTTPCode_Target_5XX_Count for Application/ELB does not exist by default

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudwatch

We are trying to set up dashboards using AWS/ApplicationELB metrics, specifically HTTPCode_Target_5XX_Count. However, this metric has never been created and I cannot see it in CloudWatch metrics list either. I guess it's because the service we're building has never had 500 errors in the past.

This does not look like a normal behaviour. According to the documentation, the reporting criteria for this metric is report if there is non-zero value. However, I was expecting HTTPCode_Target_5XX_Count metric to be created without any 500, since it's a default CloudWatch metric.

Am I missing something here? Should we artificially cause 500 errors on our service so that this metric gets created?

Comment: You usually have 2 metrics that track 5xx one on loadbalancer and one on the target. Do you find those metrics? HTTPCode_ELB_5XX_Count and HTTPCode_Target_5XX_Count

Comment: They're slightly different from each other. We want to use target metric, since we're more interested in 5xx errors happening in the target rather than the ELB itself

Comment: Okay, mentioned it just so you know. These metric should exist by default. Can you see the metrics in the CLI?

Comment: I just ran into this problem. Did they show up if you triggered an error?

Comment: yes, the metric only gets created if there is 5xx error and this is what we have observed in our system too.

Comment: facing same issue. cant create an alarm since it has not occurred yet